# Solving a separable IVP

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> $\cos(y)\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{-t\sin(y)}{1+t^2} \\
> y(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}$

As $y(1)=\frac{\pi}{2}; \ \sin(y(1))=1$; we have by continuity that there exists $h>0$:
$$\sin(y(t)) \neq 0; t \in J=(1-h,1+h)$$

And in such an interval $J$:

\begin{align*}
& -\frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}\frac{dy}{dt}=\frac{t}{1+t^2} \\
\iff & \frac{d(-\log(|\sin(y)|))}{dt}=\frac{d(\frac{(\log(1+t^2)}{2})}{dt}
 \\
\iff & -\log(|\sin(y)|)+\log(|\sin(y(1))|)=\frac{\log(1+t^2)}{2}-\frac{\log(2)}{2}
 \\ 
\iff &2\log(|\sin(y)|)=\log(2)-\log(1+t^2) \\[7pt] \iff &
\log((\sin(y))^2)=\log \Bigl( \frac{2}{1+t^2} \Bigr) \\[7pt] \iff &
\sin(y)=\sqrt\frac{2}{1+t^2} \quad (\sin(y(1))=1) \\[7pt] \iff &
y=\arcsin\Bigl(\sqrt\frac{2}{1+t^2}\Bigr); I_y=[1, \infty)
\end{align*}

Is the solution and interval of existence correct? Any further suggestions for another approach?

Comment: I was considering an interval that would contain $t=1$, maybe I should rewrite it as $I_y$

Comment: $I_y=(-\infty,-1] U [1,\infty)$